# Checking if it is possible to set the scrolling wallpaper in Android

Tags: android, scroll

Now i working at wallapapers application, and have one problem. At screen with setting wallpaper i have 3 buttons: all picture | picture without scroll | picture with scrolling !
In 1 & 2 cases all good, but in 3 i dont know how get from system, this option.
Now in my code i check where android version < 2.3.6 or getDesiredMinimumWidth() <= 0 then button with scroll enabled:

```
if (wpm.getDesiredMinimumWidth() <= 0 || 
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {  
            float tmp_width = opt_display_width*2 / metrics.density;

            opt_display_width_tmp_scroll = (int)tmp_width;

            scrollable_available = true;
        } else {
            opt_display_width_tmp_original = opt_display_width;

            scrollable_available = false;
        }
```

But it worked just for android 2.3.6 version, and how i get parameter for other  with android version 4 | 3